# Way to easily identify all default fonts in applications?

Tags: linux, debian, fonts

Debian Kwheezy (a Debian Wheezy spin with KDE), came bundled with every imaginable font and hundreds of fonts that are there to support various foreign languages in their extended character sets.  A majority of the fonts are essentially duplicates of a few basic fonts within the English characters.  There are also duplicates where essentially the same fonts from different publishers are included.  I need to cull these because Debian is running on a small external disk and available space is in short supply.

The system font is identifiable from the system settings panel.  However, many applications define their own default font.  I don't want to delete a font and then discover that an application doesn't work because I deleted its default font.  It would be a job to go through every application, find where it specifies the font, and build a "do not delete" list.  Is there a simple way, like a command to generate a list of font dependencies, to identify all fonts that existing applications expect to find?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
find /usr/share/fonts -type f -atime +30
```

which will show all fonts that have not been accessed in last 30 days. You can then do

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/VeraMoIt.ttf
```

to find out in what debian package that font is (so you can remove it).

WARNING: it assumes your filesystem is mounted with full *atime* (access time) support. You can verify it is working by checking if file access time is modified when file is accessed:

```
% ls -l --time=atime /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/VeraMoIt.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 54508 Oct 24 18:44 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/VeraMoIt.ttf
% sleep 2m
% file /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/VeraMoIt.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/VeraMoIt.ttf: TrueType font data
% ls -l --time=atime /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/VeraMoIt.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 54508 Oct 24 18:46 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/VeraMoIt.ttf
```

(in example above we show current atime, sleep 2 minutes, read the file (using file(1), but any read-only command would do), and then check current atime again. If it has changed (like ours did: from **18:44** to **18:46**) then atime support is working. We could use `stat` instead of `ls -l --time=atime` too)

If it is not working (eg. atime does not update), then you should check your `/etc/fstab` for your "/usr" or "/" paritition (or on whichever partition your */usr/share/fonts* directory is) and make sure it has `strictatime` and not any other option with `atime` in the name, and then reboot for changes to take affect, and use all your apps so all fonts get accessed before trying to find unused fonts again.

Note that there is reason why (depending on your Debian/kernel version) atime support might be disabled - it reduces performance a little (it has to do a little write every time you read a file); so if the performance gains are more important to you then the ability to find when files were accessed, you might want to put `relatime` or `noatime` in `/etc/fstab` again when you are finished cleaning your fonts.

Comment: Thanks.  That gets me a step closer (and gave me an education).  In my case, there are a lot of applications that I keep available even though I use them only rarely or have not yet used them.  I suppose I could just open every application and then try this.

Comment: yes, you could - you would just use /usr/bin as a path for find ... you can find more info about reducing size od debian installation https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian